# TSQL (SQL Server) Sorting and paging with row_number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pagination

I have a database (`SQL Server`) and app which fetches data and converts them into `JSON`.

I wrote a `T-SQL` query to order data by `userid` column (`DESC`) and take only first `10` rows, but it causes problem returning wrong results.

For example if I have following table:

```
      UserID
      ---
      User1
      User2
      User3
      ...
      User10
      ..
      User25
```

I want to to `UserID` to be `DESC` and get first ten results (then second ten results, etc). Simple saying I am looking for `MySQL LIMIT` substitute in `SQL Server`.

My query

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT  
       system_users_ranks.RankName,
       system_users.userid,
       system_users.UserName,
       system_users.Email, 
       system_users.LastIP, 
       system_users.LastLoginDate,
       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY system_users.userid) as myrownum
    FROM     
       system_users 
    INNER JOIN
       system_users_ranks 
       ON system_users.UserRank = system_users_ranks.rankid 
   ) as dertbl  
WHERE myrownum BETWEEN @startval AND @endval 
ORDER BY userid DESC
```

I can't move `ORDER BY` to inner `SELECT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need it in the inner `SELECT`.

`ROW_NUMBER` has its own `ORDER BY`, and the final presentation is defined by the outermost `ORDER BY` anyway.

Your current query will work just fine.

Comment: OMG! You're so right ... havent notice that ... Thank you very much! I need to master up my MSSQL skils ;-) I will mark it as answer ASAP. Thx!